# How do I correctly configure eslint to lint JSX files in SublimeText3

Tags: sublimetext, reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to run eslint against JSX files in SublimeText3 using the SublimeLinter plug-in.

My .eslintrc file is as follows:

```
{
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    }
}
```

But nothing in my JSX files gets linted.
Can't seem to find anything to kick it into action...

Comment: I searched for "eslintrc JSX", one of the first hits was https://gist.github.com/jfsiii/f6605306fe5f6646e9fd, is there anything about that that didn't work for you? (and if you've not tried that yet, [shame on you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I'm not using "standard" style, nor am I using babel, so this gist is not applicable.

Comment: In my case the problem was newer version of eslint doesn't come with rules by default - I didn't realise that had changed when I upgraded. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem was that the newer versions of eslint come without any default rules turned on. If you want the older flavour of default rules, you can set them in your .eslintrc file like:

```
{
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "plugins": [ "react" ],
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "modules": true,
        "jsx": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-alert": 2,
        "no-array-constructor": 2,
        "no-caller": 2,
        "no-catch-shadow": 2,
        "no-empty-label": 2,
        "no-eval": 2,
        "no-extend-native": 2,
        "no-extra-bind": 2,
        "no-implied-eval": 2,
        "no-iterator": 2,
        "no-label-var": 2,
        "no-labels": 2,
        "no-lone-blocks": 2,
        "no-loop-func": 2,
        "no-multi-spaces": 2,
        "no-multi-str": 2,
        "no-native-reassign": 2,
        "no-new": 2,
        "no-new-func": 2,
        "no-new-object": 2,
        "no-new-wrappers": 2,
        "no-octal-escape": 2,
        "no-process-exit": 2,
        "no-proto": 2,
        "no-return-assign": 2,
        "no-script-url": 2,
        "no-sequences": 2,
        "no-shadow": 2,
        "no-shadow-restricted-names": 2,
        "no-spaced-func": 2,
        "no-trailing-spaces": 2,
        "no-undef-init": 2,
        "no-underscore-dangle": 2,
        "no-unused-expressions": 2,
        "no-use-before-define": 2,
        "no-with": 2,
        "camelcase": 2,
        "comma-spacing": 2,
        "consistent-return": 2,
        "curly": [2, "all"],
        "dot-notation": [2, { "allowKeywords": true }],
        "eol-last": 2,
        "no-extra-parens": [2, "functions"],
        "eqeqeq": 2,
        "key-spacing": [2, { "beforeColon": false, "afterColon": true }],
        "new-cap": 2,
        "new-parens": 2,
        "quotes": [2, "double"],
        "semi": 2,
        "semi-spacing": [2, {"before": false, "after": true}],
        "space-infix-ops": 2,
        "space-return-throw-case": 2,
        "space-unary-ops": [2, { "words": true, "nonwords": false }],
        "strict": [2, "global"],
        "yoda": [2, "never"]

    } }
```